# react component instantiates a class but is duplicating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component (this is just a simplified example)

import Timer from './timer.js';

```
function Clock()
{
    useEffect(()=>{
        oTimer= new Timer();
    });
... etc

}
```

then inside my timer.js

```
class Timer{
   constructor(){
      this.interval = setInterval(()=>console.log('triggered'), 1000)
   }

}
```

so the problem is that for everytime my Clock component redraws on the DOM, the Timer duplicates again.... so every 1 second it prints triggered 4 or 5 times.

trying the [] empty param solved the redrawing twice... but consider the following...

I instantiate the class for oSlider... then when the props change (ie the component redraws with additional slides, I want to re init (recalc slide show length based on number of slides etc)

BUT, when I call the useEffect on the props update, then oSlider is false

```
  var oSlider = false;
    useEffect(()=>{
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow").length>0)
        {
            console.log("drew slider again");
            oSlider = new Slider(600, document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow")[0]);
        }
    },[]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        /// oSlider is is false still... 
        console.log("trying to trigger initi", oSlider)
    },[props]);
```

Answer (score 2):

To make an `useEffect(...)` that only triggers once on Mount you should add an empty array to it's dependencies.

try:

```
function Clock()
{
   useEffect(()=>{
       oTimer= new Timer();
   }, []);
... etc

}
```

EDIT:

As HMR pointed out, you can also return a function inside of any useEffect so it will be called on unMount.

implying that your Timer class has an `endTimer` method, your code would look like so

```
function Clock()
{
    useEffect(()=>{
        oTimer= new Timer();
        return () => oTimer.endTimer()
    }, []);
... etc

}
```

Comment: The useEffect callback can return a cleanup function, maybe mention that as well as OP maybe wants to stop timer when component unmounts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Adding another answer since you did an edit with a whole new question/doubt.

The reason your `oSlider` variable 'stays' as false is because of this `var oSlider = false;` line. That sentence will be executed everytime your functional component has new arguments (i.e `props` changes), therefore, resetting to `false` your previous `oSlider` variable.

To fix this you can use the `useState` hook to mantain the state of `oSlider`.

Try:

```
    // Instatiate oSlider with 'false' as its initial value 
    const [oSlider, setOSlider] = useState(false);
    useEffect(()=>{
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow").length>0)
        {
            console.log("drew slider again");
            // set new value for oSlider
            setOSlider(new Slider(600, document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow")[0]));
        }
    },[]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        /// oSlider will have the last value setted using 'setOSlider(...)' 
        console.log("trying to trigger initi", oSlider)
    },[props]);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: so the state is a way of saving variables across component reloads in essence?

Comment: Yup. Since React uses the functional paradigm it needs this  `useState` hooks (or `this.state = {...}` & `this.setState({...})` in previous versions) to handle it's component states. Otherwise any state info will be deleted as soon as the functions (Components) ends.